# System.ArgumentNullException on options.TokenValidationParameters on JwtBearerDefaults

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I am unable to run my program. I have upgraded from .net 5 to .net 6 and then .net 7. The startup.cs file has gone and I have migrated the services.AddAuthentication() method to a new file called IdentityServiceExtensions.cs. This is then in a folder called extensions. The file is executed through the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);
```

Code below

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                // error message appears on the line below
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding
                        .UTF8.GetBytes(config["AppSettings:Token"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context => 
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && 
                            path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Error message below

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentNullException
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in 
System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Value cannot be null.'
at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
at Vitrad.API.Extensions.IdentityServiceExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0. 
<AddIdentityServices>b__1(JwtBearerOptions options) in 
D:\Documents\softwareApp\softwareApp.API\Extensions\IdentityServiceExtensions.cs:line 38
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.<>c__3`1.<GetOrAdd>b__3_0(String name, 
ValueTuple`2 arg)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 
valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd[TArg](String name, Func`3 
createOptions, TArg factoryArgument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1. 
<InitializeAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows the app setting isn't defined.

```
null at...

at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
```

For this peice of code make sure the appsetting token is set. The error states you're passing in a null value.

```
new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["AppSettings:Token"])) 
//config["AppSettings:Token"] needs a value
```

,